# Are there infinitly many prime numbers in this sequence?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider the sequence
$$S_n=1+n!\sum_{k=1}^{n} k$$
Some values of n such as 1,2,3 and 4 give prime outputs. Others, such as n=11 give a composite number. The question is are there infinitely many n such that $S_n$ is prime?
All I managed to do is rewrite the sum with the well known expression to get:
$$S_n=1+n!\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
But I have no clue how to proceed from here.

Comment: This is [A300559](http://oeis.org/A300559).  Keep in mind that it isn't even known whether or not there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$ (or any other polynomial, excluding obvious cases that can't have many primes).  If it's false, maybe one can hope to prove that, but if it is true I can't imagine that there's much hope of proving it.

Comment: Very surprising that someone arrived at this expression independently !

Comment: @lulu slight correction : The case of degree $1$ is also fully solved. In two variables we have the proven result that $a^2+b^4$ with positive integers $a,b$ produces infinite many primes.